# MySQL to find rank of specific user if multiple users have same values

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a table like this that keeps a total counts of a users against different types.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `records` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `records` (`id`, `sub_id`, `count`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'asfand', 200, 1),
(2, 'saba', 70, 2),
(3, 'faisal', 250, 1),
(4, 'ali', 250, 1),
(5, 'khan', 100, 1),
(6, 'sidra', 150, 1),
(7, 'ayesha', 300, 1);
```

I want to get rank of specific sub_id against `type` = `1` only.

So let me rank people based on highest count score in desc order.

```
+----+--------+-------+------+------+
| id | sub_id | count | type | rank |
+====+========+=======+======+======+
| 7  | ayesha | 300   | 1    | 1    |
| 3  | faisal | 250   | 1    | 2    |
| 4  | ali    | 250   | 1    | 3    |
| 1  | asfand | 200   | 1    | 4    |
| 6  | sidra  | 150   | 1    | 5    |
| 5  | khan   | 100   | 1    | 6    |
+----+--------+-------+------+------+
```

I already have a query that returns the above second table, Which works fine. But I want to get rank of a specific user.

For example, If I want to find rank of `ayesha`, it is `1`. Similarly If I want to find the rank of `asfand`, it is `4`.

But When I try to find the rank of `Faisal`, it returns `2` and similarly for `ali`, it returns the same rank '2'.

Below is my query, its working fine for all records, but if 2 people have same count, then it is not working properly, it is returning rank 2 for faisal and ali both.

```
SELECT count(count)+1 AS rank 
FROM records WHERE count > (SELECT count FROM records WHERE sub_id= 'ali' and type = 1) 
AND type = 1 ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Here is my sql [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44be28/6) and please note that I have over 1 millions rows for each record.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I have over 5m rows and increasing and each type have more than 1 million.

Comment: And you want to rank all of them at once ?

Comment: No, i want to get only for sub_id that i need, So in my app, if user ali is login, it will show his rank, if faisal is login, it will show his rank, but on leaderboard section it shows top 100, leaderboard section is working fine. But for current user, it not working fine.

Comment: Then, what criteria should be ranking among those two people ?

Comment: For criteria, we can use primary key of table in asc order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function such as

```
SELECT q.rnk
  FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `count` DESC, `id`) AS rnk,
                r.*
           FROM `records` AS r
          WHERE `type` = 1 ) AS q
 WHERE q.`sub_id` = 'ali' -- 'faisal'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9c4f61fd27af7f22146315276ff9aaa)</kbd>

most probably you're currently using `DENSE_RANK()` or `RANK()` functions(*including `ORDER BY count DESC`*) those may yield equal rank values unlike to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Thanks, pretty nice, it worked like a charm and faster. I was also using R0W_NUMBER() query to find the ranking of all users, it also working, But I had issues for finding against specific number. By the way, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea not to rank all rows, but only count to the row you want sounds good. But your ranking is incomplete, because you only consider the column `count` in your ranking, while in case of ties you also want to use the column `id`. (You mention this in your request comments.) The query becomes less readable though:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.count) AS rnk
FROM records r
WHERE r.type = 1
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM records r2
  WHERE r2.type = 1
  AND r2.sub_id = 'ali'
  AND (r.count > r2.count OR (r.count = r2.count AND r.id <= r2.id))
);
```

I suggest two indexes for this:

Assuming that the name (`sub_id`) is more selective than the type (generally speaking there are few types, but many names), you can provide this index to look up the desired row quickly:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON records (sub_id, type, count);
```

Then you want to look up all rows by their count column, so provide another index for this. Again I am assuming that the count column may be more selective than the type column.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON records (count, type);
```

If the type column happens to be extremely selective (e.g. there are a million rows in the table, but only 100 with type 1), then move type to the first position in these indexes.